# libxml2 xpath parsing, doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, xpath, libxml2

I decided to use `libxml2` parser for my qt application and im stuck on `xpath` expressions. I found an example class and methods, and modified this a bit for my needs. The code

```
QStringList* LibXml2Reader::XPathParsing(QXmlInputSource input)
{
    xmlInitParser();

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx;
    xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj;
    QStringList *valList =NULL;

    QByteArray arr = input.data().toUtf8();  //convert input data to utf8
    int length = arr.length();
    const char* data = arr.data();

    doc = xmlRecoverMemory(data,length); // build a tree, ignoring the errors
    if(doc == NULL) { return NULL;}

    xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc); 
    if(xpathCtx == NULL)
    {
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        xmlCleanupParser();
        return NULL;
    }

    xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST "//[@class='b-domik__nojs']", xpathCtx); //heres the parsing fails
    if(xpathObj == NULL)
    {
        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        xmlCleanupParser();
        return NULL;
    }

    xmlNodeSetPtr nodes = xpathObj->nodesetval;
    int size = (nodes) ? nodes->nodeNr : 0;
    if(size==0)
    {

        xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
        xmlFreeDoc(doc);
        xmlCleanupParser();
        return NULL;
    }
    valList = new QStringList();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        xmlNodePtr current = nodes->nodeTab[i];
        const char* str = (const char*)current->content;
        qDebug() << "name: " << QString::fromLocal8Bit((const char*)current->name);
        qDebug() << "content: " << QString::fromLocal8Bit((const char*)current->content) << "\r\n";
        valList->append(QString::fromLocal8Bit(str));
    }

    xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return valList;
}
```

As an example im making a request to [http://yandex.ru/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a7p4.jpg) and trying to get the node with class `b-domik__nojs` which is basically one div.

```
xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST "//[@class='b-domik__nojs']", xpathCtx); //heres the parsing fails
```

the problem is the expression `//[@class='b-domik__nojs']` doesn't work at all. I checked it in firefox `xpath` ext., and in opera developer tools `xpath` ext. in there this expression works perfectly.

I also tried to get other nodes with attributes but for some reason `xpath` for ANY attribute fails. Is there something wrong in my method? Also when i load a tree using `xmlRecover`, it gives me a lot of parser errors in debug output.

---

Ok i played a bit with my `libxml2` function more and used `"//*"` expression to get all elements in the document, but! It returns me only the elements in the first children node of the body tag.                   [This is the yandex.ru dom tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a7p4.jpg)

so basically it gets ALL the elements in the first div `"div class="b-line b-line_bar"`, but doesnt look for the other elements in other child nodes of the `<body>` for some reason.

Why can that happen? Maybe `xmlParseMemory` doesnt build a full tree for some reason? Is there any possible solution to fix this.

Comment: Ok. A small update, i passed the tree and i figured out that it FAILS to build completely by the function `xmlRecoverMemory`. It builds only the html,head,body,and first `div` in the tree. So my question is that now, how can i build a Valid tree ignoring all the errors???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright it works now, if my mistake was to use xml functions to make html documents into a tree. I used htmlReadMemory and the tree is fully built now. Some code again

```
xmlInitParser();


xmlDocPtr doc;
xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx;
xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj;


QByteArray arr = input.data().toUtf8();
int length = arr.length();
const char* data = arr.data();

doc = htmlReadMemory(data,length,"",NULL,HTML_PARSE_RECOVER);

if(doc == NULL) { return NULL;}


xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc); 
if(xpathCtx == NULL)
{
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();
    return NULL;
}
xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST "//*[@class='b-domik__nojs']", xpathCtx);
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is really strange that the expression works anywhere, because it is not a valid XPath expression. After the axis specification (`//`), there should be a nodetest (element name or `*`) before the predicate (the condition in square brackets).

```
//*[@class='bdomik__nojs']
```

Comment: i tried it like so: `xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression(BAD_CAST "//*[@class='b-domik__nojs']", xpathCtx);` now i get   xpathObj->nodesetval length = 0...

Comment: by length i mean nodesetval->nodeNr;

Comment: Is there any alternative on qt for libxml2? Can use QXmlQuery on the QDomDocument? I tried to set just plain page content like ` query.setFocus(resp->response);
    query.setQuery("html[@xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']/head/title/text()");` but query.isValid() return false.

Comment: @SirLanceloaaat: `xmlns` is not an attribute, it is a namespace.

Comment: What is a right syntax to define html namespace? my code broke btw it was like this `html[@xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml']` in the other examples iv seen it like this `query.setQuery("doc('index.html')/html/body/p[1]");` but im using query.SetFocus() on a string with html content, so i need to use it on a QString inside query. How should i define a namepsace in that situation?